# R: Comparing Subgroups From Different Datasets

Tags: r, join

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset that contains the heights and weights of people from Canada - using the value of height (cm), I split weight (kg) into bins based on ntiles, and calculated the average value of var2 within each ntile bin:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtools)
set.seed(123)
canada = data.frame(height =  rnorm(10000,150,10), weight = rnorm(10000,90, 10))

Part_1 = canada %>% 
  mutate(quants = quantcut(weight, 100),
         rank = as.numeric(quants)) %>%
  group_by(quants) %>% 
  mutate(min = min(weight), max = max(weight), count = n(), avg_height = mean(height))

Part_1 = Part_1 %>% distinct(rank, .keep_all = TRUE)

> Part_1
# A tibble: 100 x 8
# Groups:   quants [100]
   height weight quants         rank   min   max count avg_height
    <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>      <dbl>
 1   144.  114.  (110.2,113.9]    99 110.  114.    100       150.
 2   148.   88.3 (88.12,88.38]    44  88.1  88.4   100       149.
 3   166.   99.3 (99.1,99.52]     83  99.1  99.5   100       152.
 4   151.   84.3 (84.14,84.44]    29  84.1  84.4   100       150.
```

For example, I see that there are 100 people between the weight range of 100.2 - 113.9 kg and the average height of these people is 150 cm

Now, suppose I have a similar dataset for people from the USA:

```
set.seed(124)
usa = data.frame(height =  rnorm(10000,150,10), weight = rnorm(10000,90, 10))
```

**My Question: Based on the weight ranges I calculated using the Canada dataset - I want to find out how many people from the USA fall within these Canadian ranges and what is the average weight of the Americans within these Canadian ranges**

For example:

- In the Canada dataset, I saw that there are 100 people between the weight range of 100.2 - 113.9 kg and the average height of these people is 150 cm
- How many Americans are between the weight range of 100.2 - 113.9 kg and what is the average height of these Americans?

I know that I can do this manually for each rank:

```
americans_in_canadian_rank99 = usa %>% 
  filter(weight > 110.2 & weight < 113.9) %>% 
  group_by() %>% 
  summarize(count = n(), avg_height = mean(height))


   americans_in_canadian_rank44 = usa %>% 
      filter(weight > 88.1 & weight < 88.4) %>% 
      group_by() %>% 
      summarize(count = n(), avg_height = mean(height))
```

In the end, I would be looking for something a desired output like this:

```
# number of rows should be = number of unique ranks
  canadian_rank min_weight max_weight canadian_count canadian_avg_height american_count american_avg_height
1            99      110.2      113.9            100                 150            116                 150
2            44       88.1       88.4            100                 149            154                 150
```

**Can someone please help me figure out a better way to do this?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: updated based on the desired output format combining the two sets:*

This can be done in a straight-forward manner using the non-equijoin functionality of `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
library(gtools)

set.seed(123)
canada = data.table(height =  rnorm(10000,150,10), weight = rnorm(10000,90, 10))
set.seed(124)
usa = data.table(height =  rnorm(10000,150,10), weight = rnorm(10000,90, 10))


## You can also use data.table to generate your Part_1 summary table
Part_1 <- canada[, .(min = min(weight),
                     max = max(weight),
                     count = .N,
                     avg_height = mean(height)), keyby = .(quants = quantcut(weight,100))]

Part_1[, rank := as.numeric(quants)]

## Join using a non-equi join to combine data sets
usa[Part_1, on = .(weight >= min,
                   weight < max)
  ## On the join result, compute same summary states by quants & rank
][, .(usa_count = .N,
      usa_avg_height = mean(height)), keyby = .(rank,
                                                quants,
  ## whenever we do a non-equijoin, the foreign key values, in this case min/max
  ## overwrite the local keys. Since we used weight twice, canadian min/max 
  ## will show up in the join result table as weight and weight.1
                                                min_weight = weight,
                                                max_weight = weight.1,
  ## To keep both sets of results distinct, we can rename columns in our "by" statement
                                                canadian_count = count,
                                                canadian_avg_height = avg_height)]
```

Gives results as follows:

```
     rank        quants min_weight max_weight canadian_count canadian_avg_height usa_count usa_avg_height
  1:    1 [55.11,66.71]   55.11266   66.69011            100            149.2101       114       149.8116
  2:    2 (66.71,69.48]   66.70575   69.46055            100            149.0639       119       148.6486
  3:    3 (69.48,71.15]   69.48011   71.13895            100            150.5331        94       148.4336
  4:    4 (71.15,72.44]   71.14747   72.43042            100            150.4779       104       149.8926
```

Also, another option would be to assign result columns for the usa table directly back to your `Part_1` summary table in place.

```
## This is a two-part nested join
Part_1[
  ## Start by creating a result that matches Part_1 ranks to all usa data
  Part_1[usa,on = .(min <= weight,
                    max > weight)
              ## Compute aggregated results on the join table result 
              ][,.(usa_count = .N,
                   usa_avg_height = mean(height)), by = .(rank)],
       ## Finaly, assign results back to the Part_1 summary table joined by rank
       c("usa_count",
         "usa_avg_height") := .(usa_count,
                                usa_avg_height), on = .(rank)]
```

Gives the following

```
            quants       min       max count avg_height rank usa_count usa_avg_height
  1: [55.11,66.71]  55.11266  66.69011   100   149.2101    1       114       149.8116
  2: (66.71,69.48]  66.70575  69.46055   100   149.0639    2       119       148.6486
  3: (69.48,71.15]  69.48011  71.13895   100   150.5331    3        94       148.4336
  4: (71.15,72.44]  71.14747  72.43042   100   150.4779    4       104       149.8926
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table` you can do this:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

dt1 <- as.data.table(usa)
dt1 <- dt1[, c("min", "max") := weight]

dt2 <- as.data.table(Part_1 %>% select("quants", "rank"))
dt2 <- cbind(dt2[,.(rank)], 
             setDT(tstrsplit(str_sub(dt2$quants, 2, -2), ",", fixed = TRUE, names = c("min", "max"))))
dt2 <- dt2[, lapply(.SD, as.numeric)]
setkey(dt2, min, max)

dt1 <- dt1[, rank := dt2$rank[foverlaps(dt1, dt2, by.x = c("min", "max"), by.y = c("min", "max"), which = TRUE)$yid]] %>% 
  select(-c("min", "max"))
```

EDIT

Totally missed the last part. But if you wish to do that, it should be relatively straightforward from the last point (you could use `dplyr` for that if you wish):

```
dt3 <- rbind(canada %>% 
               mutate(quants = quantcut(weight, 100),
                      rank = as.numeric(quants),
                      country = "Canada") %>%
               as.data.table(),
             copy(dt1)[, country := "USA"], fill = TRUE)
dt3 <- dt3[,.(count = .N, avg_height = mean(height)), by = c("rank", "country")] %>% 
  dcast(rank ~ country, value.var = c("count", "avg_height")) %>% 
  merge(dt2 %>% rename("min_weight" = "min", "max_weight" = "max"), by = c("rank"), all.x = TRUE)
```

EDIT 2

Alternatively, you could try to do something similar using `cut` function without learning anything from `data.table`

```
rank_breaks <- Part_1 %>% 
  mutate(breaks = sub(",.*", "", str_sub(quants, 2)) %>% as.numeric()) %>%
  arrange(rank) %>% 
  pull(breaks)

# Here I change minimum and maximum of groups 1 and 100 to -Inf and Inf respectively. 
# If you do not wish to do so, you can disregard it and run `rank_breaks <- c(rank_breaks, max(canada$weight))` instead  
rank_breaks[1] <- -Inf
rank_breaks <- c(rank_breaks, Inf)

usa <- usa %>% 
  mutate(rank = cut(weight, breaks = rank_breaks, labels = c(1:100)))
```

Comment: @ Darmist: thank you for your answer! I ran this line of code:

Comment: dt1 <- dt1[, rank := dt2$rank[foverlaps(dt1, dt2, by.x = c("min", "max"), by.y = c("min", "max"), which = TRUE)$yid]] %>% 
    select(-c("min", "max"))

Comment: And I got the following error: Error in `[.data.table`(dt1, , `:=`(rank, dt2$rank[foverlaps(dt1, dt2,  : 
  Supplied 999802 items to be assigned to 10000 items of column 'rank'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

Comment: Do you know what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much!

Comment: It is hard for me to say without seeng what is actually going on, my guess would be that you haven't fully ran the code or ran some additional, as it works fine on my machine. But if for some reason that is not the case, I added an alternative solution, that should be more understandable and simple (and works with `dplyr`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fuzzyjoin` for this.

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)

# take percentile ranges and join US data
us_by_canadian_quantiles <- Part_1 |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  distinct(rank, min, max, height_avg_can = avg_height) |> 
  fuzzy_full_join(usa, by = c(min = "weight", max = "weight"), match_fun = c(`<`, `>=`))

# get count and height average per bin
us_by_canadian_quantiles |>
  group_by(rank) |> 
  summarize(n_us = n(), 
            height_avg_us = mean(height),
            height_avg_can = first(height_avg_can)
            )
#> # A tibble: 101 × 4
#>     rank  n_us height_avg_us height_avg_can
#>    <dbl> <int>         <dbl>          <dbl>
#>  1     1   114          150.           149.
#>  2     2   119          149.           149.
#>  3     3    94          148.           151.
#>  4     4   104          150.           150.
#>  5     5   115          152.           150.
#>  6     6    88          150.           149.
#>  7     7    86          150.           150.
#>  8     8    86          150.           151.
#>  9     9   102          151.           151.
#> 10    10    81          152.           150.
#> # … with 91 more rows
```

Note that there are a number of cases in the US frame which fall outside of the Canadian percentile ranges. They are grouped together here with `rank` being `NA`, but you could also add ranks 0 and 101 if you wanted to distinguish them.

I should note that `fuzzyjoin` tends to be much slower than `data.table`. But since you have already gotten a `data.table` solution, this might be more to your liking.